# Custom table sort using jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table with three columns (ID, Date, and Source). I want to sort this table based on the **Source Column**. **I don't want to sort either alphabetic or numeric.** I want them sorted like all the rows from ON sources will appear first in the table, after then all the rows from MB source, and so on using either **Javascript** or **jquery**. I searched almost all the threads related to sorting. But I failed to solve this problem. I am new to this so please help me to get this done. Your help is really appreciated.

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Source</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2012-01-01</td>
    <td>ON</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>2013-06-05</td>
    <td>MB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>2011-07-08</td>
    <td>AB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2012-01-01</td>
    <td>ON</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2012-01-01</td>
    <td>MB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: maybe you want this [Jquery UI sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)..

Comment: Do you have that data in some sort of javascript array, right? How did you get that HTML?

Comment: I used HTML for illustration only. If I display this data, then it will look like the above.

Comment: what are the `so-on`'s  ..looks like canadian provinces. Are the `source` values known?

Comment: Yes the source values are known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can make array of the order since source is known and use that array index to sort by

```
var sorters =['ON','AB','MB']

var $rows = $('tr:gt(0)').sort(function(a, b){
    var aSrcIdx =sorters.indexOf( $(a).find('td:last').text() );
    var bSrcIdx = sorters.indexOf( $(b).find('td:last').text());

    return aSrcIdx >  bSrcIdx;    
});

$('table').append($rows);
```

I left the html alone but it could certainly be improved with data attributes to make this more efficient

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3jyn0qoo/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's how I've done something like this. Given the element a data-* attribute with an integer value of the priority.

Then sort them using js' `sort()` function like so:

```
$(elementsToBeSorted).sort(function(a, b){
    return $(a).attr('data-priority') - $(b).attr('data-priority');
}).appendTo('body');
```

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
$('tr').not($('.th').parents('tr')).sort(function(a, b){
    return $(a).children('td').last().text() - $(b).children('td').last().text();
}).appendTo('table');
```

This sorts all rows that are do not contain headings by text within the last table-data element.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to sort source data before putting it into the DOM. Assuming `data` is array to display, you can write something like this:

```
var data = [
    {id: 50, date: '2012-01-01', source: 'ON'},
    {id: 94, date: '2013-06-05', source: 'MB'}
];

var sortedData = data.sort(function (a, b) {
    var weights = ['ON','MB'];

    return weights.indexOf(a.source) - weights.indexOf(b.source);
});
```

This way array `sortedData` will be ordered according the order of elements in `weights`.