# jQuery table sort code only working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used charlietfl's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227960/custom-table-sort-using-jquery-or-javascript) question in StackOverflow to sort the months column in my HTML table from January to December. I just modified a few things so I could use it on my Website. I am also using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) so I could sort the other table columns alphabetically. The problem is that it only works on Mozilla Firefox. Other browsers won't sort the months column. Sometimes
the tr that wraps the table headers jump out of the thead tag and goes inside the tbody tag. Here's my table: http://makzel.com/problems/

What could be causing this?

Here's my full jquery code:

```
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    var $window = $(window);

    $window.ready(function(){

        // Enable sorting for tables
        $(".tablesort").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                0: {
                    sorter: false
                }
            }
        }); 

        // Sort by month
        $('.tablesort th').click(function(){
            var sorters =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

                    var $rows = $('tr:gt(0)').sort(function(a, b){
                        var aSrcIdx =sorters.indexOf( $(a).find('td:first').text() );
                        var bSrcIdx = sorters.indexOf( $(b).find('td:first').text());

                        return aSrcIdx >  bSrcIdx;    
                    });

            $(this).closest('.tablesort').append($rows);
        });

        // Tablesort header background change on click
        $(".tablesort th").click(function(){
            $('.tablesort th').not(this).removeClass('sorted');
            $(this).toggleClass('sorted');
         });

        function postOverflow() {
            if ($window.width() < 768) {
                $('.tablesort').closest('.post').css("overflow","scroll");

            } else{
                $('.tablesort').closest('.post').css("overflow","none");
            }
        }
        postOverflow();
        $window.resize(postOverflow);

    }); // Ready

})(jQuery);
```

Here's the link of it showing the tr tag jumping out of the thead tag: http://cms5.revize.com/revize/haddonfield/departments/table_sort_test/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), try returning -1 to put `a` below `b`, 0 to leave them unchanged, or 1 to put `b` below `a`.
Try replacing:

```
return aSrcIdx > bSrcIdx;
```

with

```
return aSrcIdx < bSrcIdx ? -1 : bSrcIdx < aSrcIdx ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Are you referring to the 0 inside the tr:gt(0) code? I'm not really that fluent in Javascript yet so I don't know what it does. I'll try changing it to -1

Comment: Yes, `return aSrcIdx >  bSrcIdx;` should be changed.

Comment: Okay. What should I replace it with?

Comment: @Chad I have edited my answer to provide the snippet.