# jQuery table sort only works in FireFox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting

My function to sort table columns works fine in Firefox but only in Firefox. I've tested Safari, IE11, MS Edge and so on.

Could anyone of you help me and may tell what's wrong in my code?

Browser console isn't showing up any JavaScript error...

```js
    $(".sortable").click(function()
    {
        var order = ($(this).hasClass("asc") ? 'desc' : 'asc');
        var table_id = $(this).closest("table").attr('id');
        var column_id = $(this).attr('id');

        if(table_id != null && column_id != null)
        {
            $.post( "test.php", { site: getUrlVars("site"), table: $(this).closest("table").attr('id'), column: $(this).attr('id'), sort: order } );
        }

        $(this).closest("table").find(".sortable").removeClass("asc").removeClass("desc");
        $(this).addClass(order);

        var colIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;
        var tbod = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
        var rows = tbod.find("tr");

        rows.sort(function(a,b)
        {
            var A = $(a).find("td").eq(colIndex).text();
            var B = $(b).find("td").eq(colIndex).text();

            if (!isNaN(A)) A = Number(A);
            if (!isNaN(B)) B = Number(B);

            return (order == "asc" ? A > B : B > A);
        });

        $.each(rows, function(index, ele)
        {
            tbod.append(ele);
        });
    });
```

Comment: i don't know where is wrong but the DOM can be not exactly the same between two browser, console.log each element to find which one don't give the same value

Comment: looks similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708828/jquery-table-sort-code-only-working-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: use debugger to see what's going on

Comment: There are some strange things in there. Firstly, jQuery's `attr` doesn't return `null`, and secondly if something is-a-number passing it through `Number` seems uneccessary. Could be browsers handle some of that strangeness differently

Comment: @adeneo - If the table doesn't even have an id it returns null in my script but it should return undefined. Strange... I'm using the newest JQuery plugin.

Comment: Question doesn't belong on SO and users name is "FakE" w/ 1pt.  This isn't worth anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

@parlad neupane

Yes, it solved my issue. Thanks!

```js
// old

return (order == "asc" ? A > B : B > A);

// new

return (order == "asc" ? (A < B ? -1 : B < A ? 1 : 0) : (A > B ? -1 : B > A ? 1 : 0));
```