# Custom sort HTML Table using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, ecmascript-6, html-table

I am following the answer given by @charlietfl on [Custom table sort using jquery or Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227960/custom-table-sort-using-jquery-or-javascript).

The table does not seem to be sorting for me.

My code:

```js
var custom_sort =['ABC','MNO','XYZ'];

var $rows = $('tr:gt(0)').detach().sort(function(a, b){
  var aSrcIdx =custom_sort.indexOf( $(a).find('td:last').text());
  var bSrcIdx = custom_sort.indexOf( $(b).find('td:last').text());

  return aSrcIdx >  bSrcIdx;

});
    
$('#mytable').append($rows);
```

```css
table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; }

#mytable { 
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='mytable'>
   <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Source</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>2011-07-08</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>2013-06-05</td>
      <td>MNO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>MNO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you see the I want to be able to rows in the order of `ABC,MNO,XYZ,ABC,MNO,XYZ`

Why isn't the code working?

How do I custom sort my table to look like:

| ID | Date | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | 2011-07-08 | ABC |
| 94 | 2013-06-05 | MNO |
| 50 | 2013-06-05 | XYZ |
| 75 | 2012-01-01 | ABC |
| 50 | 2012-01-01 | MNO |
| 50 | 2012-01-01 | XYZ |

Comment: Use some library, it's a too common issue to have to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const customSort = ['ABC','MNO','XYZ'];

const rows = [...$('tr:gt(0)').detach()];
const iMax = rows.length * customSort.length;
const sortedRows = [];
for (let i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
  const targetValue = customSort[i % customSort.length];
  const targetRowIndex = rows.findIndex(row => {
    return $(row).find('td:last').text() === targetValue;
  });
  if (targetRowIndex !== -1) {
    const targetRow = rows.splice(targetRowIndex, 1)[0];
    sortedRows.push(targetRow);
  }
}
sortedRows.push(...rows);

$('#mytable').append(sortedRows);
```

```css
table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; }

#mytable { 
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='mytable'>
   <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Source</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>2011-07-08</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>2013-06-05</td>
      <td>MNO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>MNO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there any way for the order to be `ABC,MNO,XYZ,ABC,MNO,XYZ`?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It should do what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

All you had to change was `return aSrcIdx -  bSrcIdx;`.

Since you need to return -1, 0, 1 from the comparator function, not boolean.

```js
var custom_sort =['ABC','MNO','XYZ'];

var $rows = $('tr:gt(0)').detach().sort(function(a, b){
  var aSrcIdx =custom_sort.indexOf( $(a).find('td:last').text());
  var bSrcIdx = custom_sort.indexOf( $(b).find('td:last').text());

  return aSrcIdx -  bSrcIdx;

});
    
$('#mytable').append($rows);
```

```css
table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; }

#mytable { 
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='mytable'>
   <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Source</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>2011-07-08</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>2013-06-05</td>
      <td>MNO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>MNO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>2012-01-01</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there any way for the order to be `ABC,MNO,XYZ,ABC,MNO,XYZ`? –

Comment: Does that column contain only 3 possible values  ?

Comment: Yes, it will only contain those 3 possible values